# How to get multiple pictures from intent

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-intent

I want to start an intent for picking multiple images.
for example when the intent refers you to the gallery to pick images,you long click and you select couple of images.i want to get the URI of this images.
how can i do that?
Thanks for the helpers

Answer (score 0):

There's no default way to do this.
Here's an activity I've created in my project for that:

```
public class GalleryActivity extends AtionbarActivity {
    // -----------------------------------------------------------------------
    //
    // Constants
    //
    // -----------------------------------------------------------------------
    public static final String EXTRA_SELECTED_ITEMS = "EXTRA_SELECTED_ITEMS";
    public static final String EXTRA_SELECT_MODE_SINGLE = "EXTRA_SELECT_MODE_SINGLE";
    // -----------------------------------------------------------------------
    //
    // Fields
    //
    // -----------------------------------------------------------------------
    private GridView mGridView;

    private GalleryAdapter mAdapter;

    private boolean mSelectSingle = false;

    // -----------------------------------------------------------------------
    //
    // Methods
    //
    // -----------------------------------------------------------------------
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_gallery);

        mSelectSingle = getIntent().getBooleanExtra(EXTRA_SELECT_MODE_SINGLE,
                false);

        findViews();
        initViews();

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }

    private void findViews() {
        mGridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.activity_gallery_gridview);
    }

    private void initViews() {
        mAdapter = new GalleryAdapter(this, R.layout.grid_item_gallery_image,
                mSelectSingle);
        mGridView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        mGridView.setOnItemClickListener(mImageClickListener);
    }

    private void updateGrid() {
        Uri uri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
        String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA,
                MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_TAKEN,
                MediaStore.Images.Media.LATITUDE,
                MediaStore.Images.Media.LONGITUDE };
        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null, null,
                null);

        ArrayList<GalleryImage> list = new ArrayList<GalleryImage>();
        if (cursor.moveToFirst())
            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                GalleryImage image = new GalleryImage();
                int columnIndex = cursor
                        .getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
                image.path = cursor.getString(columnIndex);

                columnIndex = cursor
                        .getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_TAKEN);
                image.date = new Date(cursor.getLong(columnIndex));

                columnIndex = cursor
                        .getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.LATITUDE);
                image.lat = cursor.getDouble(columnIndex);

                columnIndex = cursor
                        .getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.LONGITUDE);
                image.lng = cursor.getDouble(columnIndex);

                list.add(image);
            }
        mAdapter.setItems(list);
        cursor.close();
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        mAdapter.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onRestoreInstanceState(@NotNull Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
        mAdapter.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        updateGrid();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.gallery_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            finish();
            return true;
        case R.id.menu_confirm:
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.putExtra(EXTRA_SELECTED_ITEMS, mAdapter.getSelectedItems());
            setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
            finish();
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    // -----------------------------------------------------------------------
    //
    // Listeners
    //
    // -----------------------------------------------------------------------

    private OnItemClickListener mImageClickListener = new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {
            mAdapter.applySelection(arg2);
        }
    };
}
```

Adapter I use (you can create your own):

```
public class GalleryAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    // -----------------------------------------------------------------------
    //
    // Constants
    //
    // -----------------------------------------------------------------------
    private static final String EXTRA_SELECTED_ITEMS = "EXTRA_SELECTED_ITEMS";

    // -----------------------------------------------------------------------
    //
    // Fields
    //
    // -----------------------------------------------------------------------
    private ArrayList<GalleryImage> mItems;
    private ArrayList<GalleryImage> mSelectedItems;
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private int mResId;
    private boolean mSelectSingle;

    // -----------------------------------------------------------------------
    //
    // Constructor
    //
    // -----------------------------------------------------------------------
    public GalleryAdapter(Context context, int resource, boolean selectMode) {
        mResId = resource;
        mItems = new ArrayList<GalleryImage>();
        mSelectedItems = new ArrayList<GalleryImage>();
        mSelectSingle = selectMode;

        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    // -----------------------------------------------------------------------
    //
    // Methods
    //
    // -----------------------------------------------------------------------
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        GalleryImage item = (GalleryImage) getItem(position);
        if (convertView == null)
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(mResId, parent, false);

        ImageView thumbnail = (ImageView) ViewHolder.get(convertView,
                R.id.grid_item_gallery_image);
        String thumbTag = (String) thumbnail.getTag();
        if (thumbTag == null || !thumbTag.equals(item.path))
            ImageManager.displayImage("file:/" + item.path, thumbnail);
        thumbnail.setTag(item.path);

        ImageView selection = (ImageView) ViewHolder.get(convertView,
                R.id.grid_item_gallery_selection);
        selection.setVisibility(mSelectedItems.contains(item) ? View.VISIBLE
                : View.GONE);

        return convertView;
    }

    public void setItems(ArrayList<GalleryImage> items) {
        mItems = items;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mItems.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int index) {
        return mItems.get(index);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int arg0) {
        return 0;
    }

    public void applySelection(int position) {
        GalleryImage image = mItems.get(position);
        if (mSelectSingle)
            mSelectedItems.clear();
        if (!mSelectedItems.contains(image))
            mSelectedItems.add(image);
        else
            mSelectedItems.remove(image);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        mSelectedItems = savedInstanceState
                .getParcelableArrayList(EXTRA_SELECTED_ITEMS);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        outState.putParcelableArrayList(EXTRA_SELECTED_ITEMS, mSelectedItems);
    }

    public ArrayList<GalleryImage> getSelectedItems() {
        return mSelectedItems;
    }
}
```

And a structure I use to store the image data:

```
public class GalleryImage implements Parcelable {
    public String path;
    public Date date;
    public double lat;
    public double lng;

    public GalleryImage() {

    }

    public GalleryImage(String path, Date date, double lat, double lng) {
        this.path = path;
        this.date = date;
        this.lat = lat;
        this.lng = lng;
    }

    public GalleryImage(Parcel in) {
        this.path = in.readString();
        this.date = new Date(in.readLong());
        this.lat = in.readDouble();
        this.lng = in.readDouble();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        return ((GalleryImage) o).path.equals(path);
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeString(path);
        dest.writeLong(date.getTime());
        dest.writeDouble(lat);
        dest.writeDouble(lng);
    }

    public static final Parcelable.Creator<GalleryImage> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<GalleryImage>() {
        public GalleryImage createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new GalleryImage(in);
        }

        public GalleryImage[] newArray(int size) {
            return new GalleryImage[size];
        }
    };
}
```

You can specify if you need multiple/single selection mode by setting `EXTRA_SELECT_MODE_SINGLE` in you intent to `true` or `false`. This code will be a very good start point.

Comment: Thank you for your answer,but i didnt understood much,can you explain more?

Comment: @user3225147 did you try at least to use this code?

Comment: i am trying to match it to my app,ill update here soon,thank you meanwhile